# ScyllaDB: Prevent duplicate entries on specific columns

Tags: database, cassandra, duplicates, nosql, scylla

I'm using `ScyllaDB` and I have a table with the following 5 columns:

```
K1 K2 V1 V2 V3
```

Where `K1` is the partition key, `K2` is the clustering key, `V1..V3` are three columns representing 3 different values in the table.

I want to prevent duplicate values from being added to the table where `K1, K2, V1 and V2` match an existing entry in table. In other words, it should not be possible to add/store more than one row where ALL 4 columns in this row match an existing row with the same values.

Is this possible to achieve with Scylla?

Thanks

Comment: You said that (K1, K2) is your primary key. This *already* means that you can only have one entry (row) with that particular key... So it's not just that you can't have two entries with the same (K1, K2, V1, V2), you actually can't have another entry with the same (K1, K2). So your assumption the question doesn't fit together. Maybe what you want to do is to add V1 and V2 to your primary key, as Botond suggested in his answer.

Comment: @NadavHar'El OK, I guess you are referring to idea discussed in [this article](https://university.scylladb.com/courses/data-modeling/lessons/basic-data-modeling-2/topic/table-and-basic-concepts/) "But, there is a problem here. The way the table is defined, each pet can only have one heart rate recorded. When we write the next value for the same pet_chip_id, with a different time, it will actually overwrite the first value" Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most reliable way to achieve that is to make all 4 of those columns be part of the primary key of the table. Keys are naturally de-duplicated or better said, a new write with a key value will just overwrite the old value with said key.
You mention that the current schema is something like this (assuming text as type for simplicity):

```
CREATE TABLE ks.tbl (
    K1 text,
    K2 text,
    V1 text,
    V2 text,
    V3 text,
    PRIMARY KEY(K1, K2)
);
```

You can change your primary key to be like this: `PRIMARY KEY(K1, (K2, V1, V2))`.
You will still be able to query based on just `K1` and `K2`, as clustering restrictions allow for only a prefix of the clustering key to be specified.